# Whats the process for taking a python function and transferring it to Django output?

Tags: python, django

I'm experimenting with Django, and had a few questions about how python functions are translated into Django outputs. Firstly, is it correct to use Http Responses to generate Django ouptut from python functions? For example, if I have a Hello world function that returns the string Hello world, is it as simple as creating another function within my views.py, and simply return an Http response of HelloWorld()? Is there a different way in which developers conduct this transition from python function to Django? Thanks.

```
def HelloWorld():
   
    return "Hello World"


def test(request):

    return HttpResponse(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: Looks good, what's your problem?

Comment: Check render method if you are looking for a shortcut to load a template.